# How to ask someone if they know how they should stay on the water in a swimming pool

Tags: phrase-request, sentence-choice

Suppose a swimming trainer wants to know if a learner know how to stay on the water (how to keep themselves on the water). What the trainer would ask the learner:

> - Can you hold yourself on the water?
> - Can you keep yourself on the water?
> - Can you remain on the water?
> - Can you stay on the water?

Comment: What do you mean with _on_ the water? There's a story about a guy who walked on water, but it doesn't make sense to ask people if they can do that. Staying _in_ the water would make sense, but that is something _anybody_ can do, so again, why ask? Do you simply mean to ask _**can you swim**_, or _**can you keep your head above the water**_?

Comment: Do you know how to *float*?  Do you know how to *tread water*? Do you know how to *swim*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be thinking of *treading water* (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**tread water**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tread#tread__30)
>   Maintain an upright position in deep water by moving the feet with a walking movement and the hands with a downward circular motion:
>   "*they were at the deep end of the pool and trod water to keep afloat*"

This refers only to actively keeping yourself afloat. If you are just lying on the water and floating, this phrase doesn't apply.

---

Your first sentence, if said, may be confused with the phrase *to hold one's own*:

> [**hold one's own**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hold-one's-own)
>   Retain a position of strength in a challenging situation:
>   "*Britain has begun to hold its own in world markets*"

In this case, your question may be interpreted as asking whether someone is able to swim, rather than if they are able to tread water.

Comment: I've never heard any speaker of AmE ever *say* "trod water"; not that it's ungrammatical; but people here tend to say "were treading water".

Comment: @TRomano: *Trod* and *trodden* are reasonably common words in British English, in my experience.

Comment: With the collocation "trod water"?

Comment: @TRomano: [According to Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trod+water%2Cwere+treading+water%2Ctreaded+water&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrod%20water%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20treading%20water%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctreaded%20water%3B%2Cc0), it's quite a common expression.

Comment: Specific question: You have *heard* (not read) people saying "trod water"?

Comment: @TRomano: Not that particular phrase, but I have heard "he trod on my toes" and "I've trodden in (a less than polite term for dog waste)."

Comment: Ah, speakers of AmE use "trod" and "trodden" too.  I was referring specifically to how we say the past tense of "tread water".

Comment: @TRomano: It's probably relevant that I don't think I've spoken to anyone about treading water in the past 5 years at least. If nothing else, I wouldn't consider it odd if I did hear it.